# ORA-01918: user 'HR' does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlcmd

I am new to SQL. I am on Windows 11 and I get this error. Someone has already asked this question but it was almost 7 years ago and I am not sure if the solutions would work in the new update and I mostly did not understand how to use solutions. I appreciate all the help.

```
SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Feb 8 17:33:44 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL> alter user hr identified by hr account unlock;
alter user hr identified by hr account unlock
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'HR' does not exist
 
SQL> alter user hr identified by hr;
alter user hr identified by hr
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'HR' does not exist'''
```

Comment: During installation, you did not install the sample databases ... so they do not exist. You need to install them.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-1E645D09-F91F-4BA6-A286-57C5EC66321D